# How to make a Tree diagram using images as vertices, that goes left to right

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

In `Graph` or `TreeGraph`, I can make the vertices images, but the tree always starts at the top.

```
TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
 VertexShape -> {1 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[4]], 
   2 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[5]], 
   3 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[6]]}, VertexSize -> 0.6]
```

[image: TreeGraph]

If I use `TreePlot` instead, then I can make the tree start on the left:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, Left]
```

[image: TreePlot]

But `TreeGraph` doesn't have the `"Left"` option and `TreePlot` doesn't have the `VertexShape` option. How can I have images in a tree that goes from left to right?

`Graph` has the `GraphLayout` Option, but I couldn't find the one that does what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's explained on the doc page of [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html). This documentation page is very long, and most of the information is under the Scope section, under specific layout methods.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1, "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You do not need to use `TreeGraph` unless you also want to verify that the graph is indeed a tree. `Graph` will do. The key is `GraphLayout`.

With this layout, the root of directed trees is not detected automatically. You can specify it automatically as I did above. With `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, it is detected, but the layout will not be identical.

---

You can also achieve the same with `IGLayoutReingoldTilford` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
IGLayoutReingoldTilford[
 Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}],
 "RootVertices" -> {1}, "Rotation" -> Pi/2
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
tg = TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, 
   VertexShape -> {1 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[4]], 
       2 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[5]], 
       3 -> Graphics[RegularPolygon[6]]}, VertexSize -> 0.6] 
   
SetProperty[tg, VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[Pi/2][GraphEmbedding[tg]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `TreePlot` with the *hidden* options `"VertexNames"`, `"VertexFrameBackground"` and `"VertexFrameStyle"`:

```
shapes = Graphics[RegularPolygon[#], ImageSize -> 90, Background -> None] & /@ 
  {4, 6, 5}; 

TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}, Left, 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 "VertexNames" -> shapes, 
 "VertexFrameBackground" -> None, 
 "VertexFrameStyle" -> None]
```

[image]